# How do i fix this Nested if command in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel doc in which I record the crashes of a certain application.

Inside one of the rows is the following

```
3/27/2016 | (Cell B39)  |   null |  mins |  null |  secs |  (Command)
```

... the command is,

```
=IF(ERROR.TYPE(B39) =3,"Hasn't Crashed Yet",IF(B39 =0, "No Crash", "Crashed"))
```

- when B39 = 0, i want it to output "No Crash".
- when B39 is any number greater than 0, i want it to output "Crashed".
- when B39 has an error, i want it to output "Hasn't Crashed Yet".

The current command outputs "Hasn't Crashed Yet" when B39 is an error, but when B39 is 0 or higher, it outputs `#N/A`.

Comment: `ERROR.TYPE` returns `N/A` if there is no error in the cell. Check [if there is an error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) first.

Comment: B39 or E39? Your narrative contradicts your sample formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
=if(isnumber(B39), if(b39>0, "crashed", "no crash"), if(iserror(b39), "hasn't crashed yet", "how'd I get here?"))
```

Comment: Loved the "HOW'D I GET HERE?"!  Nice to have flavour on the error message.

Comment: Essentially that was put in to cover the logic hole that was not covered in the original parameters; specifically if B39 was text or blank. I did not know how to proceed with those scenarios so I made tried to make it obvious that an unplanned result was occurring.